# Process flow dissapears from loop in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a loop in my unity code that reads a .csv text file and adds the contents to a class which is then added to a List object.

The problem I have is that the code in the below method never completes, that is it never gets to the debug.log statement at the bottom of the loop, if I try to make a call from inside the loop the (I shouldn't call it a thread here) thread just stops, and I get no error message in the console.

```
void ReadDataFile()
{
    Debug.Log(getPath() + DataFileName);
    string fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(getPath() + DataFileName);
    string[] lines = fileData.Split("\n"[0]);
    Debug.Log("linecount from csv is : " + lines.Length);

    for(int n = 1;n < lines.Length; n++)
    {
        Debug.Log("LINE=" + lines[n]);
        string[] linedata = (lines[n].Trim()).Split(',');
        if (linedata[0] == null) break;
        geoData data = new geoData();
        data.Name = linedata[(int)enumField.NAME];
        data.Lat = linedata[(int)enumField.LAT];
        data.Long = linedata[(int)enumField.LONG];
        data.LocType = linedata[(int)enumField.TYPEOFLOCATION];
        data.Charts = linedata[(int)enumField.CHARTS];
        data.Vhf_Tel = linedata[(int)enumField.VHF_TEL];
        data.GroundtoAnchor = linedata[(int)enumField.GROUNDTOANCHOR];
        data.Possibilities = linedata[(int)enumField.POSSIBILITIES];
        data.Environment = linedata[(int)enumField.ENVIRONMENT];
        data.Transportation = linedata[(int)enumField.TRANSPORTATION];


        //add to list
        PortData.Add(data);
        Debug.Log(data.Name + " " + data.Lat + " " + data.LocType);
        /*
        float lat = (float)GeoAngle.FromDegrees(data.Lat);
        float lng = (float)GeoAngle.FromDegrees(data.Long);
        Debug.Log("Adding marker at:" + lat + " " + lng);
        Vector2 markerGeo = new Vector2(lat, lng);

        Debug.Log("Plot vector2 is: " + markerGeo);

        OnlineMapsMarker3D current = control.AddMarker3D(markerGeo, MapMarker);
        */

    }

    Debug.Log("portdata saved to class is : " + PortData.Count);
}
```

Comment: I should also point out that all the debug statements inside the loop print to the console what I expect.  It doesn't crash the app, as other parts of the app are running fine.  It just never reaches the last Debug.Log("portdata saved to class.......

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting comments.  That said, I don't see anything that would create an infinite loop.  Have you tried simply attaching a debugger and seeing what line it is blocked on?

Comment: Can you wrap all the code inside of ReadDataFile in a try/catch and then set a breakpoint in the catch to see if an error is thrown?

Comment: It stopps when I try to call out to an method outside the loop or when the loop finishes

Comment: put a Try catch inside the loop, to see if something crashes inside of it

Comment: If I wrap it in a try/catch,  I don't know what error to try to catch, so I can't see what is happening, But it's definitely catching something......Ahh sorry me being bleary eyed, systemexception

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, it was an index out of range exception, strange that it wasn't picked up by the Unity console.

Comment: I noticed that Unity sometimes (at least in the older versions) ignores any exception other than null reference exception.

Comment: This is in 2018.3.6, but funny I don't get any other "standard" exceptions to the debug.log either, 1st time I've ever encountered it, but I solved it with the try catch advise above, so all good :)